# JavaScript onkeydown handling

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Before the button ("play") is clicked, the program handles `keydown` but after clicking the button which draws a table, thereafter `keydown` messages are not handled.
I want this to work in IE or Firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var matrix,xbody,ybody,dir,key;
function draw()
{
    for(var i=0;i<xbody.length;i++)
    {
        matrix[xbody[i]*50+ybody[i]].bgColor="black";
    }
alert("draw");
}
function init()
{
document.write("<table id='mine' align='center' height='500px' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' width='500px' border='4' >");
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
    document.write("<tr>");
    for( var j=0;j<50;j++)
    document.write("<td></td>");        
    document.write("</tr>");
    }
document.write("</table></div>");
matrix=mine.getElementsByTagName("td");
xbody=new Array();
ybody=new Array();
xbody[0]=ybody[0]=0;
draw();
alert("pop");
}

function keypress(e)
{
alert("aiyoooo");
if((e.keyCode==38)|| ((e.which)&&(e.which==38)))
key=0;
else if((e.keyCode==40)|| ((e.which)&&(e.which==40)))
key=1;
else if((e.keyCode==37)|| ((e.which)&&(e.which==37)))
key=2;
else if((e.keyCode==39)|| ((e.which)&&(e.which==39)))
key=3;
}   
</script>
</head>
<body onkeydown=keypress(event)>
<br/>
<input type="button" onClick="init()" value="play">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answer would be rather long just => [look here](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/07/11/insert-in-place-without-documentwrite/)

in short document.write is just not the right way to go.
use smth different like document.createElement or go for a nice'n'easy javascript framework like jquery.

there you could just

```
var html = "";
html += "<table id='mine' align='center' height='500px' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' width='500px' border='4' >";
html += ...
$(html).appendTo("body");
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read this article: http://java-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/javascript_documentwrite_tutorial

> The document.write command must be
>   carried out during the loading of the
>   page. So, if it is attached to any
>   event that executes after the page has
>   loaded, then the whole page will be
>   replaced with the contents of the
>   document.write command.

Rather than using `document.write`, you might want to instead use `getElementById` and then put your HTML in the `innerHTML` property of the element that you want the text to be in.

That may require adding a new `div` to hold the new text.

Comment: This. Also, use something like `document.getElementById('mine')` instead of just using `mine` directly (which should only work in quirks mode).